# I can't use ES6 module with typescript in my Node.js project

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tsconfig, ts-node

I want to use both typescript and the es6 module in my Node.js project, and in addition, I want the files compiled to the javascript language to have the es6 module.

This is my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "arep",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --exec ts-node app.ts",
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.4.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mysql2": "^3.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.17",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  }
}
```

And this is my tscongif.json :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

Here is the error I get :

```
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /home/rznkolds/Desktop/Standart/2- Development/2- Applications/1- NodeJS/arep/app.ts
    at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:160:9)
    at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:203:36)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:141:22)
    at async nextLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:865:22)
    at async nextLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:865:22)
    at async Hooks.load (node:internal/modules/esm/hooks:448:20)
    at async handleMessage (node:internal/modules/esm/worker:196:18) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
}
```

When I do this with the commonjs module, everything works fine, but when I do it with the es6 module, I get this error.
I couldn't find much resources about this error. In many places, people solved the problem by turning it into the CommonJS module.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering is because Node.js does not natively support ES modules (ESM) as of version 14.x. This means that when you try to run a .ts file with the type set to "module" in your package.json, Node.js will throw an error because it doesn't know how to handle .ts files.

To resolve this issue, you have a few options:

1. Use the esModuleInterop option in your tsconfig.json file. This will
   allow TypeScript to emit code that is compatible with both CommonJS
   and ESM. However, this might not be ideal if you want to strictly
   use ESM.
2. Use the .mjs file extension for your TypeScript files. This tells
   Node.js to treat the file as an ESM module. You would need to update
   your package.json to point to the .mjs file:

```
    {
  "name": "arep",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.mjs",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --exec ts-node app.mjs",
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.4.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mysql2": "^3.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.17",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  }
}
```

3. Use the --esModuleInterop flag when running your TypeScript files
   with ts-node. This will enable the same interoperability as the
   esModuleInterop option in your tsconfig.json file.
4. Upgrade to Node.js 16.x or later, which has experimental support for
   ES modules. You can enable this experimental feature by running
   Node.js with the --experimental-modules flag.

Personally, I would recommend using the .mjs file extension approach, as it most closely aligns with your goal of using ES modules in your Node.js project.

Comment: So which one do you recommend between ESM and CommonJS? The reason I want ESM is that I want it to be more readable when compiling the code into javascript language.